# Is there any available SMS Pdu parser in Java?

Tags: java, sms, gsm, pdu

Anyone knows a available Pdu Parser in Java from byte[] array, my main concern is to get the User Data Header (UDH) complying to the GSM standard. I mean getting it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[smsLib](http://smslib.org/) is relatively mature. You could also make use of the parser built into Android.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to parse the Pdu to generate the UDH using the built-in Android parser, do you have experience with this?

Comment: Yes, I have used the utilities in the library to achieve my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As I was in need of an SMS-PDU parser/creator a couple of years ago I could not find one and had to write my own. Grab a copy of GSM 03.40, brush up on your bit-fiddling skills, and get going. :)

Comment: Seems like this will be the case, but hopefully someone could share.

Comment: I’m still digging in my old archives, I might still have that stuff somewhere but don’t hold your breath.